# mysql: count number of site visits with last visited time

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I am saving ip address of visitor and time of visits.

Now I want to query my table in such a way that it gives me total no. of site visits from an ip address with the last time of visit.

for example suppose this is my table:

```
ip              time
-------------------------------
1.1.1.1       23-feb-2016 09:40 

1.1.1.1       24-feb-2016 09:45 

1.1.1.1       25-feb-2016 09:50 

1.1.1.2       26-feb-2016 09:55 

1.1.1.2       27-feb-2016 10:00
```

now i want my result to be like this:

```
   ip               time        count
----------------------------------------
1.1.1.2       27-feb-2016 10:00    2 

1.1.1.1       25-feb-2016 09:50    3
```

i am using this query :

```
$query = "SELECT ip, time, COUNT(*) as count FROM ip_table GROUP BY ip ORDER BY time DESC";
```

but it is not giving me the last visited time from a particular ip address.

my output is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This. its give you last visit time

```
SELECT ip, MAX(time) AS 'time', COUNT(*) as count 
FROM ip_table 
GROUP BY ip
```

if you want to order by overall max time of all indivisual id then you can use order by time

```
SELECT a.id, a.time, a.`count` FROM 
(
SELECT ip, MAX(time) AS 'time', COUNT(*) as count 
FROM ip_table 
GROUP BY ip
)as a
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

link [JSFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4dcc2a/2)

Comment: thanks for your answer. its working like a charm. but i have one doubt ...why have you used ` while referring count (a.`count`) to  in this line .....SELECT a.id, a.time, a.`count` FROM

Comment: because i created alias of subquery (`as a`) here you can write count without alias its working but whenever you join two table and in both table you have same column name then you must be use column with alias which table's column you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT ip, MAX(time), COUNT(*) as count 
FROM ip_table 
GROUP BY ip;
```

No order by time is needed. Give it a try and see if it works for you.